# python flask request.args.get not returning all

Tags: python, flask

When i do `https://example.com/short?url=https://example.com/authorize?client_id=869029507019&scope=8`, it only print out `https://example.com/authorize?client_id=869029507019`. How to make to print out all of them?

```py
@app.route("/short")
def profilepage():
    url = request.args.get("url") 

    if url is None:
        return '{"code": 400, "message": "url missing"}'
    
    url = (formaturl(url))
    randomlink = id_generator()
    
    client.insert_one({"link": randomlink, "redirect": url})

    return '{"code": 200, "message": "https://linker.kro.kr/' + randomlink + '"}'
```

Comment: what do you mean by print out all of them? there is only one argument you are sending in the get request(url=......) there aren't any other args. if you are also passing some other argument such as test you can get that using request.args.get('test')

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The ampersands in the URL you are passing as a GET parameter needs to be encoded.

Consider:

```
example.com/?url=http://example.org/?a=apple&b=banana
```

With this you are expecting the request to `example.com` to contain the GET parameter `url` set to `http://example.org/?a=apple&b=banana`

However the `url` parameter ends at the first ampersand, so infact the get parameters passed to `example.com` are:

```
url=http://example.org/?a=apple

b=banana
```

---

Now consider this test app:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    url = request.args.get('url')
    return url # Simply display the received URL in the browser

@app.route('/form')
def form():
    # A form to demonstrate auto encoding
    return '''<form action='/'>
                <input type='text' name='url'>
                <input type='submit'>
              </form>'''
```

If you load the `/` endpoint, and manually provide a URL in the browser, the incorrect behaviour will be observed.  Take this URL manually pasted in to the address bar:

```
http://localhost:5000/?url=http://example.org/?a=apple&b=banana
```

The response body is:

```
http://example.org/?a=apple
```

Now access the `/form` endpoint, and paste the same URL in the text field, and submit.  Note the URL in the address bar now contains the encoded values (this is built-in HTML form behaviour):

```
http://localhost:5000/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2F%3Fa%3Dapple%26b%3Dbanana
```

And the response body will contain:

```
http://example.org/?a=apple&b=banana
```

Search around for other resources, such as how to encode URLs like this with Javascript, etc.